# Looping in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am new to Oozie. Can someone please help me with this requirement?

I had a Java code, in that I had an `ArrayList` which holds file names.
Suppose if my `ArrayList` contains 10 files, then looping through each of the file in the List, I have to call another `Pig` and `Hive` action in Oozie.

I have explored on this and found that direct looping is not supported in Oozie, and I may have to use `oozie sub workflows`.

So could someone please help me with the approach I need to give to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic loops are not supported in oozie.

In your scenario I would suggest the below approach.

1. Create a Java code that generates the workflow.xml dynamically.
2. This workflow.xml should have your 1st java action then the inner hive and pig action, then iterate these actions again and again till the loop finishes. Note action names should have some flag , so that each loop action has different name only then the oozie would execute the workflow.

Your workflow would have say :

Loop 1 - Javaction1, hiveaction1 and pigaction1

Loop 2. Javaction2 , hiveaction2 and pigaction2

Hope it helps.